# Email confirmation token is not working in Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I am trying to implement email confirmation/verification feature for my identity server users. In my case i have 2 apps, one is for Web API to add Identity server users and another is for a web app to provide the login to the users.

I have followed [this document](https://code-maze.com/email-confirmation-aspnet-core-identity) and able to generate the token for user email confirmation. Here i am forming a  URL for identity web app and attaching the token, email as query parameters.

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Account", new { token, email = user.Email }, Request.Scheme);
var message = new Message(new string[] { user.Email }, "Confirmation email link", confirmationLink, null);
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(message);
```

Using the above code generated the URL similar to this.

```
https://identitywebapp/Account/ConfirmEmail?token=CfDJ8MnpbdKNEB1Orar2rO6jqk3aK1mqnU9i%2BbAkMbV7Bpu91NhOGVCv8ad4x8pFw8tzRPrixaJNJPMsQVXhBxywNdZvCsN0PiqXZJxem45JblNQEy4gaMVDeFgu8wlGIBtXwi&email=admtest3@mailinator.com
```

Below is my **ConfirmEmail** method implementation.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    if (user == null)
        return View("Error");
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
    return View(result.Succeeded ? nameof(ConfirmEmail) : "Error");
}
```

I am getting the "Invalid Token" issue when calling the _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);

Answer (score 0):

I did a look at their source code and found the solution:

```
public async Task<bool> VerifyResetEmailTokenAsync(string email, string newEmail, string token) {
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

    var isValidToken = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(
        user,
        _userManager.Options.Tokens.ChangeEmailTokenProvider,
        $"ChangeEmail:{newEmail}",
        token
    );

    return isValidToken;
}

public async Task<string> GenerateEmailChangeTokenAsync(Guid userId, string newEmail) {
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());

    try {
        var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, newEmail);
        return token;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle the exception (log, rethrow, or return a specific error message)
        throw new Exception("Failed to generate email change token.", ex);
    }
}
```